# How to replace id with matching value in another table/list?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, list

I've got two tables like the following:

```
Table A           Table B
a_id              b_id
a_name            b_name
                  a_id
```

I've got a List of everything from each table. When I bind the data source to a control, how can I replace the a_id in Table B with the a_name from Table A? I want to display:

```
b_id
b_name
a_name
```

I would prefer achieving this without accessing the database again, since I've got all the information in List A and List B. Any suggestions?

Comment: If list A and list B are generics lists you can use the c# join keyword

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it is a simple `JOIN` operation:

```
SELECT A.a_name, B.b_id, B.b_name FROM B INNER JOIN A ON A.a_id = B.a_id
```

Comment: Yes, I know that's the easy way to do it. But I would prefer to do it without accessing the db again, just working from the lists.